# Python cookiecutter without remote git repository

Tags: python, git, cookiecutter

I have recently discovered cookiecutter and would like to try the structure for some of my work projects, but we can't always push code to a remote repo (even a private one). I often use git locally just to track changes for my own purposes. Is there a way to run `cookiecutter /my/local/folder` to set everything up without a remote repository?

I have tried

```
cd /my/local/folder
git init
cookiecutter /my/local/folder
```

but get the error message:

> "A valid repository for for "/my/local/folder" could not be found in the following locations:
>   /my/local/folder"

Comment: Have you tried creating a git repository in `/my/local/folder`? You shouldn't have to push it anywhere.

Comment: I think so, that is what I was trying to do with the `git init` command above. I can run `git status` successfully in the directory but cookiecutter still doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry I missed that. You should also try commiting all the files in `/my/local/folder`. If cookiecutter is trying to pull from the repository, there will be nothing to pull if you don't commit.

Comment: I left it empty initially, and just committed a sample text file. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: On inspecting the cookiecutter source code, a repository is not considered valid unless it contains a `cookiecutter.json` file. It doesn't appear as though a git repo is necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Michael Mior is spot on, that error results when the root of the cookiecutter does not contain a `cookiecutter.json` file. The check for this is performed by `repository_has_cookiecutter_json` in [repository.py](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/blob/master/cookiecutter/repository.py)

From the documentation one may point to a path ending in `.git`, which is weird, but this seems like a convention more then it is a norm. See `https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/pull/1184` for more the most current information regarding this. In `determine_repo_dir` in [repository.py](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/blob/master/cookiecutter/repository.py) it appears as though the existence of the directory is checked but that this is never probed for a version control implementation.

Cookiecutter, for the moment, appears to ignore any version controlled local repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, when you need to render a template, using a local cookiecutter project, here is an example command for how you can do it :

```bash
cookiecutter --no-input /path/to/your/local/cookiecutter_project/ --checkout branch_to_use --config-file your_config.yml
```

When you use a remote, the command will simply reference the url of the remote repo, as follows for a github project for example :

```bash
cookiecutter --no-input https://github.com/repo/project.git --checkout branch_to_use --config-file your_config.yml
```

Hope it helps